# Have no idea with python-excel read data file

Tags: python, excel

I am a student and haven't a big expirence to do this work.
So problem is next.
I have a part of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import cmath
def sf(prompt):
""" """
    error_message = "Value must be integer and greater or equal than zero"
    while True:
        val = raw_input(prompt)
        try:
            val = float(val)
        except ValueError:
            print(error_message)
            continue
        if val <= 0:
            print(error_message)
            continue
        return val
def petrogen_elements():
    """Input and calculations the main parameters for
    pertogen elements"""
    print "Please enter Petrogen elements: \r"
    SiO2 = sf("SiO2: ")
    Al2O3= sf("Al2O3: ")
    Na2O = sf("Na2O: ")
    K2O =  sf("K2O: ")

    petro = [SiO2,TiO2,Al2O3,]                    

    Sum = sum(petro)

    Alcal = Na2O + K2O
    TypeA lcal= Na2O / K2O
    Ka= (Na2O + K2O)/ Al2O3 

    print  '-'*20, "\r Alcal: %s \r TypeAlcal: %s  \
     \r Ka: %s \r" % (Alcal, TypeAlcal,Ka,)

petrogen_elements()
```

So the problem is next. I have to load and read excel file and read all data in it. After that program have to 
calculate for example Alcaline, Type of Alcaline etc.
Excel file has only this structure

```
   1    2     3     4    5     
1 name1 SiO2 Al2O3 Na2O K2O
2        32  12    0.21 0.1
3 name2 SiO2 Al2O3 Na2O K2O
4        45    8   7.54  5
5 name3 SiO2 Al2O3 Na2O K2O
6. … …. …. …
…
…
```

All excel file has only 5 columns and unlimited rows.
User has choice input data or import excel file.
First part of work I have done but it stays a big part 
Finally I need to read all file and calculate the values.

I would be so grateful for some advice

Comment: If you can transform the excel file to csv, you could just use the built-in [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this website http://www.python-excel.org/ that lists all the major Python excel related libraries.
I personally have tried XLRD -the first one listed- and found it great, and it has a neat documentation.

I have also done some work using it while the Presidential elections took place in Egypt as there were lots of data in an excel sheet that we needed to import into a mysql database. I have published the code on Github : https://github.com/mos3abof/egypt-elections-misc

First install xlrd

The script you will come up with should be something like:

```
from xlrd import *
## Opening the excel file
book = open_workbook('excel_file.xls')

## Reading the sheet we need
## Most probably the data will be on the first sheet, 
## otherwise this needs to be updated
our_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

## Get the rows number
rowcount = our_sheet.nrows

## Looping over sheet rows
for i in range(rowcount -1):
    ## Get the data in the row
    our_row = our_sheet.row_slice(i+1)

    ## Access each row by index and do whatever you like with it
    ## Since you have 5 columns, the index will range from 0 - 4
    print our_row[0]
    print our_row[1]
    print our_row[2]
    print our_row[3]
    print our_row[4]
```

You can find a working example from the script I mentioned above in this file : https://github.com/mos3abof/egypt-elections-misc/blob/master/elections_import_excel.py

Comment: Thank you a lot) this is realy helped)